# for each input type get value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the input type value's from input fields that have been generated by a webshop framework. I can't change the html. When I added fields it creates this:

```
<input id="filter_15" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="15">
<input id="filter_16" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="16">
<input id="filter_17" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="17">
```

I found some code that gets the value based on the input id, except that the id's filter_... can change, and are different for every shop.

any sugestions? here's what i've gathered so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var filter;
function onload() {
    filter = document.getElementById('filter');
}
function show() {
    alert(filter.value);
}
```

Comment: maybe `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');` is usefull here. It'll return your a node list containing all the inputs of the type checkbox. Then you can loop over them and get the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track with `.getElementById`, but you want instead, `.getElementsByName`.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByName("filter[]");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
  alert(els[i].value);
```

```html
<input id="filter_15" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="15">
<input id="filter_16" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="16">
<input id="filter_17" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="17">
```

Answer (score 3):

By using  `document.querySelectorAll`, in which you can use any CSS selector with, including an `"attribute starts with"` selector like `input[id^="filter_"]` must get your job done.

Here is a demo

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="filter_"]');
debugger;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    alert(inputs[i].value)
}
```

```html
<input id="filter_15" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="15">
<input id="filter_16" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="16">
<input id="filter_17" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="17">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get inputs by tag name, then iterate over it.

```
    var inputs, index, len;

    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    len = inputs.length;

    for (index = 0; index < len; ++index) {
        alert(inputs[index].value)
    }
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter but your solution selects more elements than necessary. Using `getElementsByName()` will lower the number of elements to loop through and therefor will be quicker.

Comment: it's not right solution, the html page might be many input fields, `getElementsByTagName()` method can't target specific elements.

Comment: The title states: "for each input type get value with javascript" That makes the other approach wrong.

Comment: That is right, I will upvote if you will make one change :). This is something that is 'wrong' in many solutions that use the `for`-loop. Don't recalculate the length of the array with every loop. Calculate the array's length before the loop, put it in a variable and use that in the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Heres the Jquery solution

```
$('input [id^="filter_"]').each(function(){
   alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: OP states that the id is not always "filter_..."

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky the OP states that only the part after the underscore might change like `filter_xxx`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky, OP is saying for id suffix(filter_....) can be changed, but it;s also not right answer, OP is looking solution in javascript

Comment: I know the solution was requested in javascript but it's always nice to know all potential solutions I think, as you will likely come across both solutions for solving this problem in other systems.